# Do Azure Functions have a request pipeline of some kind?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I would like to add some common authentication code to a collection of `HttpTrigger` Azure Functions (v3), which I'm using as an API. I know about the service-side auth associated with `AuthorizationLevel.Function`, but that won't work for me. The type of auth I need to do is relatively simple: just check a specific HTTP header for a specific value.

In ASP.NET, this kind of thing can be done in an `HttpModule`. Do Azure Functions have a similar request pipeline of some kind?

As far as I can tell from the documentation, it looks like new Function instances can call `Startup.Configure()` before calling the target method, if the project is appropriately configured. However, those calls are intended to support Dependency Injection, and don't have access to the `HttpRequest` object.

Obviously, I could just put an `isAuthorized(request)` call at the beginning of each API entry point, but that feels klunky, repetitive, and potentially error-prone. Is there a better way?

Comment: Although Function Filters (`IFunctionInvocationFilter`) initially seemed like the logical choice here, I don't see a good way for them to return an HTTP error code to the client without adding more code to the called method--which defeats the whole point of using them.

Comment: Yeah your `isAuthorized(request)` seems to be the solution for function app